# How do I set full trust for a single Web Part in SharePoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts, full-trust

I am looking to set full trust for a single web part, is this possible?  manifest.xml maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried registering the assembly in the GAC? This is the preferred approach to giving any assembly full trust on your machine:

```
gacutil.exe \i C:\Path\To\Dll.dll
```

Hope that helps. Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I am deploying my custom made webparts with a CAB file and 'stsadm -o addwppack', will this be in the GAC?  How can I check?

Comment: naspinski - probably better to edit your question to clarify the CAB package, people may not see your comment here

Answer (score 3):

As far as I recall manifest.xml is correct, and you specify the CodeAccessSecurity.

This article has a detailed description about it 
http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2007/07/05/how-to-configure-code-access-security-for-a-web-part.aspx

when you deploy your solution then you deploy it with the -allowCasPolicies flag on

I'm not sure i'd want to put a webpart into the GAC

Answer (score 1):

You can install a CAB packaged web part to the GAC using

```
STSADM -o addwppack -filename yourwebpart.cab -globalinstall
```

If you are using WSP packages you need to set attributes in the manifext.xml file

```
<Assembly Location="yourassembly.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache">
```

and call

```
STSADM -o AddSolution -filename yourwebpart.wsp

STSADM -o DeploySolution -name yourwebpart.wsp -allcontenturls -immediate -force -allowGacDeployment
```

Of course you shouldn't really install to the GAC if you can help it, setting CAS is the preferred way.